# Lazy initialization in Spring DataJPA

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, lazy-loading

happy new year:)

I have a Spring MVC project using Hibernate and DataJPA.

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
private User user;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "restaurant_id", nullable = false)
@NotNull
private Restaurant restaurant;
```

As you can see, here is two fields with eager fetch. I want to make both a lazy. I need to user `@NamedEntityGraph` annotation asI made here:

```
    @NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = Restaurant.GET_BY_ID, query = "SELECT r FROM Restaurant r WHERE r.id=?1"),
    })
    @Entity
    @NamedEntityGraph(name = Restaurant.GRAPH_WITH_MENU_HISTORY, attributeNodes = {@NamedAttributeNode("menuHistory")})
    @Table(name = "restaurants")
    public class Restaurant extends NamedEntity {

        @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "restaurant")
        @OrderBy(value = "date DESC")
        private List<Dish> menuHistory;

        public static final String GRAPH_WITH_MENU_HISTORY = "Restaurant.withMenuHistory";
```

I want to know, if I'll write

```
@NamedEntityGraph(name = "G_NAME", attributeNodes = {@NamedAttributeNode("user", "restaurant")})
```

and if I'll request one of them, will the second load anyway or it will load only by request to him? May be, I need to user two graphs?

Comment: "if I'll request one of them" - one of what? "will the second load anyway" - what will load anyway? "or it will load only by request to him" - to who? :) Make question more explicit.

Comment: @djxak I mean class fields "user" and "restaurant" :)

Comment: How you would to query the entity consisting the `user` and `restaurant` fields? Where is your *repository* code?

Comment: @djxak I didn't write this part yet, but here is a my code from another class with one lazy field, I'll do it similarly:

Comment: @djxak, 

@NamedQuery(name = User.GET_BY_ID, query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.id=?1")

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to JPA 2.1 Spec 3.7.4:

> The persistence provider is permitted to fetch additional entity state
>   beyond that specified by a fetch graph or load graph. It is required,
>   however, that the persistence provider fetch all state specified by
>   the fetch or load graph.

So actually the `@NamedEntityGraph` just guarantees what fields should be eagerly loaded, but not what fields should not be loaded.

So, if you make `@NamedEntityGraph` with `user`, your persistence provider (Hibernate for example) can load only `user` field or both `user` and `restaurant` fields eagerly. This is dependent on implementation and not guaranteed.

See [this](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9270) hibernate's issue.

But as far as I know, the Hibernate loads only simple fields in addition to specified in `@NamedEntityGraph`, and not loads lazy associations.

So if you use hibernate, it should work.

But of course you need two separate `@NamedEntityGraph`s for `user` and `restaurant` fields.

Or you can use [ad-hoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.10.6.RELEASE/reference/html/#jpa.entity-graph) `spring-data-jpa`'s feature:

```
@Repository
public interface GroupRepository extends CrudRepository<GroupInfo, String> {

  @EntityGraph(attributePaths = { "members" })
  GroupInfo getByGroupName(String name);

}
```

With this code you don't need explicitly declare `@NamedEntityGraph` anymore. You can just specify fields inline.